# Is a perfboard made using phenol formaldehyde resin toxic to touch/inhale?

Tags: pcb

It seems that [perfboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfboard) is made of phenol formaldehyde resin.

> The substrate is typically made of paper laminated with phenolic resin
> (such as FR-2) or a fiberglass-reinforced epoxy laminate (FR-4).

It seems that phenol can be absorbed by the skin and has acute/chronic hazards. https://www.epa.gov/sites/production/files/2016-09/documents/phenol.pdf And isn't formaldehyde the thing that keep evaporating from MDF and causes chronic disease? https://www.hse.gov.uk/woodworking/faq-mdf.htm

So, is a perfboard made of phenol formaldehyde resin safe to touch with bare hands and leave inside a closed room?

Comment: Phenol formaldehyde resin is not formaldehyde any more than salt is chlorine.

Comment: In other words it is fine to hold, at least, just like MDF is fine to hold. You probably shouldn't store mountains of PCBs in an air tight bedroom, but you shouldn't do that with a lot of things.